# Control key not working on embedded terminal (mac os)

Tags: intellij-idea

I probably changed some setting by mistake, how do I get the control key to work again??

**Given** I open a terminal in IntelliJ (2016.2.3)
**And** I run a command that takes some time to run
**When** I press `control + c` 
**Then** I should see the command being aborted 
**Instead** I see the letter c is typed instead.

Basically the `control` key is not working at all in the embedded terminal.

The same scenario works on **webstorm** and **iterm**. So it's definitely **IntelliJ**

Comment: This is happening to me too since the upgrade to 2016.2.3. It was working yesterday before I upgraded. So I don't think it's a setting, unless they introduced a new one.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm going to try reverting to 2016.2.2. I think I have the installer somewhere. Good to know.

Comment: Just reverted, indeed it works in the previous version.

Comment: Bug report and workaround here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160416

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since my last answered, a new version (2016.2.**4**) of IntelliJ has been released. This new version fixes the problem.

Comment: 2016.2.5 fixes it as well, so jetbrains managed not to re-introduce the bug :)

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: Revert to previous version

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 seems to have a bug that prevents the control key to be sent to the terminal. I reverted to the previous version and it fixed it for me.

This is not the best answer, but it's the only way I could find to fix it. Thanks @charles-o for pointing out that he started seeing this problem after updating.

Comment: upgrade to 2016.2.4 and fix it